# Steps when calculating limits in 2 points

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am looking for a guideline or hints on how to know if you should check for 2 one-sided limits or one "whole" limit.

I know that when there is an $|x|$ in the denominator that you should check for $x<0$ and $x>0$ and thus (possibly) becoming 2 one sided limits. What other cases require attention for this problem?

(P.S. I only recently started learning about limits)

Comment: $y=arctan(1/x)$ at $x=0$

Comment: Even more simply, $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac 1x$ does not exist because the limit differs on each side approached.  $\lim_{x\to 0^-} \frac 1x \to -\infty$, whereas $\lim_{x\to 0^+} \frac 1x \to \infty$.